# Pegar dados apos gridComplete

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Eu preciso pegar o json completo retornado pela consulta do jqGrid, como faço?

```
...
gridComplete: function(data) {
   console.log(data); //não funciona
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O objeto que o loadComplete recebe é um Json com paginação e um atributo **rows** com a lista de dados retornados. uma outra opção para você pegar os dados é utilizar o exemplo abaixo:

```
var data = $("#suagrid").jqGrid('getRowData');
console.log(data );
```

você pode colocar dentro do evento de loadComplete **mas lembrando que o complete já recebe como argumento os dados!**

Comment: vlw me ajudo mto!!